# How to use an asset in Android Ui?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, frontend

I am new to Android Studio. While working on front end its sometimes easy to take some parts as png file and place it on the particular position instead of recreating it in xml  file. I am confused can we use png all the time ? I am worried about memory space . Like the app contains 50 pages and in each page I use 1-2 assets . I don't want my app to have more than 40mb. What will be the best way to do? Can we store the image as a URL and retrieve it whenever we use. What's the drawback in that way?

Comment: Unless the PNG image is a graphic, you can always recreate one using `Drawables` which takes barely any space. So, if the images you're talking about contain just some background colors or gradients or shapes, you should use `Drawables`. You can create custom shapes very easily. Images take space and it's hard to reduce their size after an extent where they stats distorting. Also, Images render in different sizes for different phones where Drawable looks same in every size.

Comment: Unless you're making a offline app, you should always prefer cloud for storing images and retrieving them later using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso). This is always the preferred way to  reduce APK size. Remeber, don't store layout resources on cloud, they should be bundled with APK.

Comment: You can use free image cloud like Imgur or Discord for storing your images without paying for a cloud service, just store the image URLs in a database and retrieve it whenever you want. The above libraries will help you caching the images which will not download same image again and again reducing the loading latency after a cold start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So many questions :)

> I am confused can we use png all the time ?

Use what's best for your picture. For a photo, a JPEG will probably do better. But if you wish, you can use PNG all the time, yes.

> I don't want my app to have more than 40mb.

Check and see. Depends on how big your images are; we can't tell.

> What will be the best way to do?

Not enough information to tell you that. In general, there's nothing wrong with using images in assets.

> Can we store the image as a URL and retrieve it whenever we use.

Yes.

> What's the drawback in that way?

You'll need to get some server space somewhere. Also, there will be a loading latency. Also, your app won't be usable while disconnected from the Internet.

> While working on front end its sometimes easy to take some parts as png file and place it on the particular position instead of recreating it in xml file.

That's the part that is confusing to me. Android XML layouts usually contain interactive elements, ones that the user can interact with. Images, on the other hand, tend to be static. What kind of XML is there out there that you think you can replace by an image?